# Bucket and calculate mean of numbers

Tags: r, aggregate-functions

Input:-

```
Month   Profit
1         90
3         30
5         50
11        10
```

Output:-

```
Month   Profit
3         60
6         50
9         0
12        10
```

I start by making the buckets.

```
Output <- data.frame(Month=seq(3,12,3))
```

I am trying to bucket the profit numbers based on the month value. All the values in month 1-3 are in 3 bucket and 4-6 are in 6 bucket etc. I want to take a mean of the profit rather than the sum. How can I do this without looping it. I tried looping but it's getting too complicated.

Edit:-

```
Output<- Input
Output$Bucket<-cut(Output$Month,seq(0,12,3),include.lowest = T,labels=seq(3,12,3))
Final<-setDT(Output)[,.(MEAN=mean(Profit)),by=Bucket]
```

Final

```
      Bucket MEAN
1:      3   60
2:      6   50
3:     12   10
```

Comment: You can use `cut` or `findInterval` to create the bucket and then get the `mean`

Comment: Then `aggregate` it.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that.

Comment: @akrun Is this the ideal way?

Comment: Hint: your sequence should start with 0 in order to include Months 1 and 2.